# Javascript : how to call a function from an html page that is in a script file

Tags: javascript, html, electron, discord.js

I have two file , one named `index.html` and an other named `index.js`
I use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) with [Electron](http://electronjs.org) to make a discord bot. My interface is in html due to electron so I have some textbox to update the status of my bot. I use [Discord.js](http://discord.js.org)

This is the code that cause some issue`index.html`:

```
<div id="ActivityChanger">
        <select id="ActivityTypeList">
          <option value="none">None</option>
          <option value="PLAYING">Playing</option>
          <option value="WATCHING">Watching</option>
          <option value="LISTENING">Listening To</option>
          <option value="STREAMING">Streaming</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="TEST" size="40" id="ActivityGame" />
        <button name="Update" type="submit" value="update-true" id="UpdateButton" onclick="UpdateActivity()">
        Update
        </button>
        <script scr="index.js"></script>
      </div>
```

This code normaly send the information of the textbox and dropdown when the `Update` button is pressed but I don't want to have Javascript in my .html file so I have the function

```
function UpdateActivity(){
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("ActivityTypeList").value;
    var selectedGame = document.getElementById("ActivityGame").value;
    if((selectedValue !== 'none') && (selectedGame !== null)){
      UserBot.user.setActivity(selectedGame, {type: selectedValue,})
      console.log('Updated Status' + ` to ${selectedValue} ${selectedGame} `)
    }
}
```

UserBot is my client

But when I press the burron , in the console , its said that `UpdateActivity()` is not defined

Comment: Is comma after `selectedValue,` is mandatory?

Comment: Theres a typo in your line - <script scr="index.js"></script>. It should be src and not scr. Fix that and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

If that’s the real HTML you’ve included, it has a typo in it:

```
<script scr="index.js"></script>
```

That should be `src`, not `scr`:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can confirm on this, i copy-pasted your code and corrected 'scr' to 'src' and 'UpdateActivity() is not defined' message no longer appears